# ClickHouse : find / highlight chains of events by condition within a session and aggregate data on them

Tags: arrays, function, events, clickhouse

I have app data with events where users add (or delete) items to their carts:

datetime, cart_id, user_id, product_id, event, **direction**

Events for adding or removing products can be as follows:

Catalog Product Add - adding one item to cart **from catalog**,
Catalog Product Quantity Change with **direction** attribute > 0 - **increasing** the quantity of added product by 1 (**from catalog**),
Catalog Product Quantity Change with **direction** attribute < 0 - **reducing** the quantity of added product by 1 (**from catalog**),

Catalog Product Remove - deleting a product / reducing the quantity of a product to 0 (no matter how much of this product was added before) **from catalog**

There are similar types of events when **the context is cart** (adding and deleting occurs on the user's **cart screen** before placing an order)

**Cart** Product Add, **Cart** Product Quantity Change  with **direction** attribute > 0,
**Cart** Product Quantity Change with **direction** attribute < 0, **Cart** Product Remove

The task is to understand **what total quantity of product was added by the user within the cart**
(taking into account all additions, quantity changes and deletions of product)

Also understand the final added quantity of product on the catalog screen and on the cart screen separately

For instance:

[image]

I hope the example is clear in the img :)
**Final quantity added = 1**  Taking into account all additions, changes and resets (0)

added quantity of product **on the catalog screen** = 2 and **on the cart screen** = -1 - All additions after which there was a remove event (up to 0) are not taken into account, so in the last chain (without removing up to 0 ) a product was added 2 times in the catalog and -1 in the cart screen

Ofc added quantity of product **on the catalog screen** +  **on the cart screen**  = **Final quantity added**

Is there any way do do it with existing functions in ClickHouse?

Thank you very much in advance!